# asp.net web app returning IIS info instead of current user credentials

Tags: asp.net, webserver, iis-6

I am working with an asp.net web application using custom authentication.  I wrote a quick test app to put out on our web server to make sure I could grab the necessary credentials from the user.  I am trying to get the current logged in user (which I have done before) using the following line of code:

```
   string username=System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
```

This normally returns a string in the format "domain\user".  What I'm getting instead is something like this: IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, is there a setting in IIS that needs to change?  Or is there a different way to grab the username?

Comment: Do you have impersonation setup in your web.config?

Comment: @Dillie-O I currently do not have impersonation set up.  I thought that it should be disabled as the asp application would be handling authentication. I did try enabling it and NT AUTHORITY\IUSR is returned to me.

Comment: Since you're using custom authentication, do you have the proper code in place to set the IPrincipal details? Without that I believe the Security.Principal class defaults to what you have

Comment: @Dillie-O It looks like this is where my problem is!  I forgot about coding for this in my test.  Thank you!

Comment: Not a prob. i'll set up and answer so that others may find it helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using custom/forms authentication, it sounds like you aren't setting the IPrinicipal details after the user is authenticated.

You can [follow this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) (find the "Creating the Forms Authentication Cookie section) on how to set this code up in your app. It isn't as difficult as it looks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Page.User.Identity.Name
```